# Gmail API returning email signature even if set as "No Signature"

Tags: email, google-api

The following api will retrieve your email signature if you have it set in gmail:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/get

However, if you add a signature then set it to "No Signature" (radio box) afterwards, it will still return the signature you set in the settings page. I expected that it should return an empty response.

There seems to be no issue reported on either the sdk or here so not sure if this is isolated. It can be replicated on google's api explorer too so it is not an issue on my sdk.

Is there a workaround for this besides clearing my signature from the settings?