# GoogleAPI- Get signature setting via API

Tags: google-api

Is there anyway to get Gmail signature setting [on/off]?

I'm retrieving signature via https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs

Unfortunately, the API does not contain any information about setting [No signature].

Answer (score 0):

From the API documentation link you provided (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs), use **patch** or **update** to change the signature.

The documentation for update (for example), explicitly mentions how signature updates are handled.  See: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/update

> Updates a send-as alias. If a signature is provided, Gmail will
>   sanitize the HTML before saving it with the alias.

Comment: Thank you for your information. But the main problem is how to get "No signature" setting which define whether user want to show their signature inside email content or not.

Comment: You likely have to set the signature to blank to "disable" it, saving the previous signature as state in your app if you want to restore it later.  From the (deprecated) Email Settings API, the documentation says to set to an "empty string" for the no signature case.  See:  https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/

Answer (score 0):

Similar question: [Gmail API returning email signature even if set as "No Signature"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44274495/gmail-api-returning-email-signature-even-if-set-as-no-signature?rq=1) but no answer yet.
Related issue on Google's issuetracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68380736, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36760480, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69721532